# Finding joint sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to find two statistics $T_1$, $T_2$ such that $(T_1, T_2)$ is jointly sufficient for $(\lambda, \theta)$ for a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ from a two parameter exponential distribution.

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-\theta)}, & \theta < x < \infty, \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$
f(x_1 ,x_2 , \ldots ,x_n |\lambda ,\theta ) = \lambda ^n e^{\lambda \theta n} \exp \bigg( - \lambda \sum\limits_{i = 1 }^n {X_i } \bigg) \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\mathbf 1}(x_i  > \theta )}, 
$$
where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the indicator function. Then note that
$$
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\mathbf 1}(x_i  > \theta )} = {\mathbf 1}(\min \lbrace x_1 , \ldots ,x_n \rbrace  > \theta ),
$$
and apply Theorem 2 given [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/466/sufficient.pdf).

Comment: Here we need to factorize $f(x_1 ,x_2 , \ldots ,x_n |\lambda ,\theta ) = u(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) v(r_{1,\ldots,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n | \lambda,\theta)$ right ? but I don't see a function $u(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Isn't $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\mathbf 1}(x_i  > \theta )} = {\mathbf 1}(\min \lbrace x_1 , \ldots ,x_n \rbrace  > \theta )$ dependent on $\theta$ ?

Comment: You can take $u(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1$ (it is nonnegative and does not depend on the parameters). As for the second question, consider the example given on p. 3 in that link (Uniform population).

Comment: Also, note the last sentence in Theorem 2.

Comment: Further, see the examples in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic, in particular the example "Uniform distribution (with two parameters)".

Comment: I kind of see that $T_1 = \sum\limits_{i = 1 }^n {X_i}$ and $T_2 = min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ are jointly sufficient (please tell me if I'm wrong) but I'm trying to reason it why. I feel like I follow the theorem and exmaples and arrive at the answer. Like always I take the joint pdf and try to separate the function but I don't understand the intuition behind it.

Comment: BTW your answer and comments helped me a lot to think about the problem rather than giving the answers straight. Thanks.

Comment: For the intuition behind this example, see, again, http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/466/sufficient.pdf (for example).

Answer (score 0):

[by neyman factorization theorem X_bar and X(1) are jointly sufficient stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRQhw.gif)

Comment: You should include the picture in your post or, better yet, write what it says using MathJax. And please include some words of explanation as well.